# Story-based audio game for GNU/Linux

Tags: linux, open-source, game

I’m looking for an [audio game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_game) that

- is **FLOSS**, and
- runs natively on **GNU/Linux**.

Actual **human voice** recordings (English), no speech synthesis.

It must be possible to play it with **keyboard** input only.

Visual output is okay, but it must not be required to play the game. So **blind** people must be able to play the game.

The game must be **story-based**, so it can be an adventure, a RPG, an interactive novel, or similar.